# Arduino UNO GSM

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, gsm, sim900

I trying get full GSM messages:

My code where I reading GSM commads:

```
void loop()
{
  int i;
  if (started) {
    incomingByte = gsm.SimpleRead();

  }
};
```

I always getting ~ 80 characters string, how I can read full GSM command ?

Output I receive:

```
D0368103012304820281828D2708012E007600650073006B00690074006500200073000B0
D0368103012304820281828D2708012E007600650073006B006900740065002000730050E61
D0368103012304820281828D2708012E007600650073006B006900740065002000730050005
D0368103012304820281828D2708012E007600650073006B00690074006500200073000F518
```

Comment: How are you getting these strings? From Serial? Are you using `print` or `write` function? Please post the full code if possible.

Comment: It looks like you are receiving the message as PDU. You will need to change to text mode. Post your entire code then we can help you. Also what kind of GSM board are you using?